# How does the process of absorption and re-emission work on the atomic level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I want to know exactly how it happens? What happens during the process of absorption and what happens during the process of re-emission?

Comment: Physics "explains" phenomena via models. So the best we can do is to describe what a particular model says. Our current best model for questions like this is QFT (Quantum Field Theory), which requires rather advanced mathematics. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I learned that electromagnetic waves induce dipole in molecules and that dipole oscillates to emit radiation or dissociate if the frequency of oscillations is high,so from that perspective i am asking how it exactly happens,not mathematically just like an explanation first and then the theoretical part.